# How to check for skipLocationChange in guards?

Tags: angular, angular6

I have some routes which should not be directly callable by url but should be navigable by angular.
Up to now I used `skipLocationChange` inside angular to call the routes and on the components I added some logic which checks if the url is the same as the component-url and if yes redirect to an error page.

*Example (meta) code*

```
// Inside routing module
{
  path: 'example_component',
  component: ExampleComponent
}

// Inside example component
ngOnInit() {
  if (currentPath.includes('example_component')) {
    navigateToError();
  }
}

// Inside some other component
goToExampleComponent() {
  this.router.navigate(['/example_component'], { skipLocationChange: true}]);
}
```

I was wondering if I could achieve the same behaviour with guards and if yes: how?